# .NET encryption

Tags: .net, encryption

I need to encrypt a couple of my user's data fields in the database (strings). The fields will only be used within the application but we want them to be as secure as possible.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Can anyone recommend a good script/class?

Is it possible to use an encryption technique that only allows for the decryptor to work if you run it on the server?

Thanks

**EDIT**:
one more question:  is it true that if no one has access to my server then is safe to store the public key within the code?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: recommended reading if not already checked: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .NET [Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) functions. have a look at the doc you probably find the solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is highly dependent on what database you have.

If you have a database that supports encrypted columns (like sql server), then just use what's already built into the database for this.

Regarding the last question "Is it possible to use an encryption technique that only allows for the decryptor to work if you run it on the server?"

No.  However, if you are using the built in database encryption, then the key is actually stored on the server itself in a protected area.. which is about as good as it's going to get.